# How to round numbers in Javascript which are line of code?

Tags: javascript

It is not single line of code.
How to round numbers in Javascript which are line of code?
How to round it to 2 decimal points?

```html
 if (aSelectedValue >= bSelectedValue) {
    document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = "0€";
    document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = "Debug3";
   } else if (bSelectedValue <= 1600) { 

     document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = (+bSelectedValue - +aSelectedValue) * 0.075 + "€";
     
   } else if (bSelectedValue <= 1900 && bSelectedValue >=1600 && aSelectedValue < 1900 && aSelectedValue >= 1600) {
    
     document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = (+bSelectedValue - +aSelectedValue) * 0.15 + "€";
    
   } else if (bSelectedValue <= 2500 && bSelectedValue >=1900 && aSelectedValue <= 2500 && aSelectedValue >= 1900) {
   
     document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = (+bSelectedValue - +aSelectedValue) * 0.5 + "€";
     
   } else if (aSelectedValue >= 1300 && aSelectedValue <= 1600 && bSelectedValue <= 1900) {
    
     document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = (1600 - +aSelectedValue) * 0.075 + (+bSelectedValue - 1600) * 0.15 + "€";
     
   } else if (aSelectedValue > 1600 && aSelectedValue <= 1900 && bSelectedValue <= 2500) {
     
     document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = (1900 - +aSelectedValue) * 0.15 + (+bSelectedValue - 1900) * 0.5 + "€";
     
   } else if (bSelectedValue <= 2500) {
    
    document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = (1600 - +aSelectedValue) * 0.075 + (+bSelectedValue - 1900) * 0.5 + 45 + "€";
    
   }
```

Here is full

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Round to at most 2 decimal places in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this?

```
var number = (1600 - +aSelectedValue) * 0.075 + (+bSelectedValue - 1600) * 0.15;
number = +number.toFixed(2);
document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = number + "€";
```

Or perhaps use a function like so:

```
function roundNum(number,amount){//amount is the rounding value, in this case, 2
    return +number.toFixed(amount);
}
roundNum(yournumber,2);
```

This allows you to round *each line of code*. **Note:**
although you could simply use `toFixed()` it can cause issues with numbers rounding incorrectly, so there's the little fix of adding `+`.

Comment: it deletes the euro sign.

Comment: here: `var number = (1600 - +aSelectedValue) * 0.075 + (+bSelectedValue - 1600) * 0.15;
number = +number.toFixed(2);
document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = number + "€";` - also updated my answer.

Comment: Ou i fell rephrase my question. It is not single line of code... That is the point!

Comment: Updated my answer with an alternative **function** you could run for each line of code.